# MySQL adapter: Missing required configuration option 'host'

Tags: mysql, composer-php, magento2

I installed Magento with composer install, nginx server. When I am trying to launch my Magento in browser I am getting Error.

An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.

I opened exception log file in my Magento2 directory and i see that error.

> [2019-06-14 18:29:16] report.CRITICAL: MySQL adapter: Missing required
>   configuration option 'host' {"exception":"[object]
>   (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): MySQL adapter: Missing required
>   configuration option 'host' at
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Type/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php:105)"}
>   []

I dont know how to fix it. Searched in google but google says nothing about that error. Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: It looks like the configuration is incomplete. After the composer install you need to set up Magento. Did you run the CLI command or the install wizard, as described in the docs? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html

Comment: Yes I think I finished all steps. But something is not working and I dont know whats that.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error during `bin/magento setup:upgrade` after performing a `php bin/magento setup:config:set ...` command for redis caching. What happened was in app/etc/env.php, Magento created an entry 'db' => 'connection' => 'indexer' where there wasn't one before. However it did not have any db info or credentials. It seems there's not much documentation on this entry in env.php. What I did was set the default database connection values here and got it working.

env.php

```
....
'db' => [
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'some_db_host',
            'dbname' => 'some_db',
            'username' => 'some_db_user',
            'password' => 'some_db_pw',
            'model' => 'mysql4',
            'engine' => 'innodb',
            'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
            'active' => '1',
            'driver_options' => [
                1014 => false
            ]
        ],
        'indexer' => [
            'host' => 'some_db_host',
            'dbname' => 'some_db',
            'username' => 'some_db_user',
            'password' => 'some_db_pw',
            'model' => 'mysql4',
            'engine' => 'innodb',
            'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
            'active' => '1',
            'persistent' => null
        ]
    ]
],  
....
```

Now I can run `setup:upgrade` with no error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your app/etc/env.php and verify the entries specific to your database.
I could fix  my instance following the solution mentioned here. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2852